# I'm trying to take a record from, for example row 1 and insert it into row 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, crystal-reports-2008

I have a field called `RecordType` that has three different records, `1, 2, 3.` Each hold different records. I want to take the the balance from another field I have called `Limit` from `RecordType 1` and insert it into `RecordType 3` but I'm just unsure on how to do this. This will be going into a Crystal Report and I want to be able to suppress the `RecordType 1` altogether.

I've tried a simple case statement but that's about it, I can't really think of any other ways to do it (I'm sure there's loads).

```
CASE
    WHEN FA.RecordType = 3 THEN
        FA.Limit
END AS LimitTest
```

## Current results

| Record Type | Limit |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5,000,301 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |

## Expected Results

| Record Type | Limit |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 5,000,301 |

Comment: what if Record type 1 also has some value like `1000`.

Comment: i mean what if Record type 1 and 3 both have some values, like in above case since type 3 has 0 so we assume to make it to `sum` or apply `max` or something like that, but what if type 1 has 5000 and type 3 has 1000 now what will be the result. You cannot just ignore the value in type 3

Comment: also record are limited to 3 type only?

Comment: @DarkRob Record Type 1 is a recurring Record Type and has multiple values.

It looks something like this:
RecordType | Limit
         1         | 5,000,301
         2         | 0
         3         | 0
         1         | 43,260,301
         2         | 0
         3         | 0
etc...

Comment: Sorry my formatting is terrible I'm not sure how to do it properly. But to answer your question no type 1 & 3 will never have the same value as 3 never has a value. I want to basically move the value from type 1 into type 3

Comment: then what is the problem in ans of @Gordon Linoff ?

Comment: It's not clear whether you are trying to `select` data for a report and, in the process, filter and alter some of the data. You also refer to inserting and updating and generally fiddling about in the original table. Do you want to change the contents of the table or extract and modify data for a report?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to combine the `limit` for types 1 and 3.  You can do this with aggregation on an expression:

```
select (case when recordtype = 1 then 3 else recordtype end) as recordtype,
       sum(limit) as limit
from t
group by (case when recordtype = 1 then 3 else recordtype end);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using sub-query and a Case statement in your select statement, for example:

```
SELECT [RecordType], 
    (CASE [RECORDTYPE] WHEN 3 THEN 
                        (SELECT LIMIT from Table_1 WHERE RECORDTYPE = 1) 
                    ELSE LIMIT END) LimitTest 
FROM TABLE_1 WHERE RECORDTYPE <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> Sorry my formatting is terrible I'm not sure how to do it properly. But to answer your question no type 1 & 3 will never have the same value as 3 never has a value. I want to basically move the value from type 1 into type 3

Which makes me think that this would be the simplest:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE RecordType = 3
UPDATE table SET RecordType = 3 WHERE RecordType = 1
```

3 never has a value so let's get rid of them first, then 1 has the value but we want it to be 3 so just update all the 1s to be 3s instead

If you're not into deleting it, just mask it instead:

```
SELECT 3 as RecordType, Limit FROM table WHERE RecordType = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move value from type 1 to type 3 then do simple update in your query.

```
   update t set t.value= t1.value from table as t , table as t1 where t.recordtype=3 and t1.recordtype=1
```

or

```
   delete from table where recordtype = 3
   update recordtype set recordtype=1 where recordtype=3
```

This will work may be

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    IIF(A.RECORDTYPE = 1,3,A.RECORDTYPE) AS RECORDTYPE,
    A.LIMIT
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 RECORDTYPE,5000301 LIMIT UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 RECORDTYPE,0 LIMIT UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 RECORDTYPE,0 LIMIT
) A
WHERE A.RECORDTYPE IN (1,2)
ORDER BY RECORDTYPE
```

Check this if works for you.